# Image of derivative mapping applied to polynomials of degree at most $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $P_n$ be the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ equipped with addition and scalar multiplication. Let $D : P_n \to P_n$ be the derivative mapping. Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\text{im}D = P_{n-1}$.

Intuitively makes sense since if $p(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x +a_0$ then applying the derivative operator to $p(x)$ I have that $\deg(Dp) = n-1$ right? Any hints on how to show this rigorously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed that $\operatorname{im} D \subseteq P_{n-1}$. To complete the proof, given a polynomial $q$ of degree at most $n-1$, can you come up with a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$ such that $Dp = q$?

Comment: Given $q(x)$ s.t $\deg(q(x)) = n-1$ I would have that $p(x) = \int q(x) \ dx$ and $\deg(p(x)) = n$?

Comment: Yes, you have that $Dp(x) = D \int d(q) = q(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. This shows that $P_{n-1}\subseteq \operatorname{im}D$ so that you have shown $\operatorname{im}(D) = P_{n-1}$.

Comment: I see, however I'm not entirely sure on what do you meant by saying that I showed that $\operatorname{im} D \subseteq P_{n-1}$. Is this equivalent with $\deg(Dp) = n - 1$?

Comment: @DanielLi Yes exactly. You took an element $p(x) \in P_n$ and you showed that $\deg Dp(x) = n-1$, i.e. $Dp(x) \in P_{n-1}$. Hence, $\operatorname{im} D \subseteq P_{n-1}.$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\operatorname{im} Dp \subseteq P_{n-1}$?

Comment: Nope. That does not make sense.

Comment: Hmm, I think my confusion is with the map $D$ here. I'm applying this to $p(x)$ and this outputs an element in $P_{n-1}$. What if I would apply $D$ to some other function, how can I be sure that the result would be in $P_{n-1}$?

Comment: Because $p(x)$ is arbitrary. You took an arbitrary $p(x) \in P_n$ and you showed that $Dp(x) \in P_{n-1}$. The key word is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

For each polynomial $p(x)$ of $P_n$ which has degree $d\geq 1$, $D(p(x)$ yields a polynomial of degree $d-1$. Moreover, if $p(x)$ is a constant and so has degree $0$, then $D(p(x))=0$.
Thus the mapping $D:P_n\rightarrow P_{n-1}$ is well-defined.

Conversely, if $p(x)=a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$ is in $P_{n-1}$, then a $D$-preimage is

$q(x)= \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}x^{n}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{n-1}x^{n-1}\ldots+\frac{a_1}{2}x^2+a_0x + c$

with arbitrary scalar $c$.

Hence,  $D$ is surjective.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you're stating that the surjectivity of $D$ is equivalent to $\text{im}D = P_{n-1}$?